# EmbeddedModelField in custom user model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I'm using django-mongodb-engine to make a site.

I have a custom user model that looks like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    trigrama = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    external_email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    AbstractUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'trigrama',
        'external_email', 'phone_number', 'username'
    ]
```

It works just fine, but then I tried adding an embedded document to the user model:

```
    permissions = EmbeddedModelField('Permission')
```

`Permission` is a class that looks like this:

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    computers = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Computer'))
    projects = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Project'))
    scripts = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Script'))
```

Now when I try to crate a user in the shell using `User.objects.create()` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 149, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 416, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 548, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 668, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1675, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 583, in execute_sql
    "field) to None!" % field.name)
IntegrityError: You can't set permissions (a non-nullable field) to None!
```

I tried setting the default to `Permission()` using:

```
permissions = EmbeddedModelField('Permission', default=Permission())
```

but then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 149, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 416, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 548, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 668, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1675, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangotoolbox\db\basecompiler.py", line 579, in execute_sql
    connection=self.connection
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangotoolbox\fields.py", line 364, in get_db_prep_save
    (embedded_model, type(embedded_instance)))
TypeError: Expected instance of type <class 'users.models.Permission'>, not <type 'unicode'>.
```

So how should I go about adding an embedded document to the custom user model?

P.S.
If I type `Permission()` in the shell it instantiates just fine, returning a `Permission object` and not a unicode.

Comment: show how you try to create User object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If you read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) about the way to set a default value for a field, you'll see that it expects to recieve a value... or [a callable object](http://djangodays.com/2009/05/11/django-foreign-key-default-value-example/). You can't just create the instance then and there, it doesn't work like that (emphasis mine):

> The default cannot be a mutable object (**model instance**, list, set,
>   etc.), as a reference to the same instance of that object would be
>   used as the default value in all new model instances.

When you call it yourself (i.e. `Permission()`) what you get is an instance, which, in turn, returns a unicode (it's calling the `__unicode__` function).

In other words, just drop the trailing `()`:

```
permissions = EmbeddedModelField('Permission', default=Permission)
```

Now, in truthfulness, this might be problematic, because it doesn't actually *saves* that new permission object, and the whole thing can become messy (this being permissions and all, you want to be extra careful). So it might be better to create a function to wrap the operation, and use that instead:

```
def get_initial_perms():
    p = Permission()
    p.save()
    return p

# later:
permissions = EmbeddedModelField('Permission', default=get_initial_perms)
```

A similar solution would be to override the `save()` method and give the object a permission before calling the acutal `save` part.